# Playing Vimeo video using HCVimeoVideoExtractor, can't get video URL with specific quality

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I'm using this lib https://github.com/superm0/HCVimeoVideoExtractor to play vimeo url. It works fine but changing the quality doesn't return videoURL for some videos. I'm talking about this line

```
if let videoURL = vid.videoURL[.Quality1080p]
```

I'm not able to understand why it doesn't return videoURL for a video when I pass Quality1080p?
How to fix it? Is there something wrong with my videos? Do I need to convert all of videos to same quality and then upload on Vimeo?

Following is my code:

```
import UIKit
import HCVimeoVideoExtractor
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func playClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://vimeo.com/1234567") else {
            print("Error url nill")
            return
        }

        HCVimeoVideoExtractor.fetchVideoURLFrom(url: url, completion: { ( video:HCVimeoVideo?, error:Error?) -> Void in
            if let err = error {
               print("Error = \(err.localizedDescription)")
               return
            }

            guard let vid = video else {
                print("Invalid video object")
                return
            }

            print("Title = \(vid.title), url = \(vid.videoURL), thumbnail = \(vid.thumbnailURL)")

            if let videoURL = vid.videoURL[.Quality1080p] {

                let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
                    playerController.player = player
                    self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
                        player.play()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: videoURL not found")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you i think. Add this to your code[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the count of your video last numbers

```
videoArr = self.arrFilterItems[indexPath.row].link
last9 = String(videoArr.suffix(9))
var last9 = String() 
here link = https://vimeo.com/(123456789) == 9 or (123456) == 6
```